# Sum of positive eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, absolute-value, trace

I have matrices of the form:

\begin{equation}
H_{BdG} = \begin{pmatrix}H&\Delta\\\Delta^{\dagger}&-H^T\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

where $H = H^{\dagger}$ and $\Delta^{\dagger} = \Delta^T = -\Delta$. The spectrum of $H_{BdG}$ is symmetric around zero: for every eigenvalue $E$ there is a corresponding $-E$.

**The quantity I am interested in is the sum of the positive eigenvalues of $H_{BdG}$.**

I want to calculate this value numerically for very large matrices. For my purposes it is very slow to directly diagonalize the matrix. I was hoping there could be a shorter way around, since I only care about the sum of the eigenvalues, not the individual ones.

I thought a possible solution (if this is even possible) could be using the trace of the matrix. The trace of $H_{BdG}$ is zero, but I was hoping there could be a smart transformation to eliminate the negative eigenvalues.

I noticed the quantity I want is equivalent to half the sum of the absolute value of all eigenvalues:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i, E_i >0} E_i = \sum_i \frac{\vert E_i\vert}{2},
\end{equation}

so maybe that's a start? I also noticed that if I wanted the sum of the squares of the positive eigenvalues, the solution would be simple: I just had to calculate the trace of $H_{BdG}^2$, since

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i, E_i >0} E_i^2 = \sum_i \frac{E_i^2}{2}.
\end{equation}

I don't know if this information might help, but the reason I want this quantity is because I want to calculate the derivative of this quantity with relation to a parameter of the matrix.

So, is this workaround even possible? If so, how?